# Is there a TextMate bundle that includes a pane to manage bookmarks across files?

Tags: bookmarks, eclipse, textmate, ide, bundle

The regular bookmark feature in Textmate does not include a pane that allows you to jump to any bookmark in any file. This feature exists in Eclipse as shown below. Are there any bookmark managers bundles in Textmate to do the same thing? It is very handy when you've inherited a huge codebase.

[image: Eclipse]